# C program not recognizing null pointer

Tags: c, insert, null, linked-list

I'm trying to recurvisely implement an insert function in C, but I'm having all sorts of issues.  I'm in an intro CS class and they started throwing C labs at us before we had ever worked with it before.  Part of the issue is that the list pointer is not being recognized as NULL and I'm also pretty sure that I'm using malloc improperly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define True 1
#define False 0
typedef int BOOLEAN;

struct Node{
int value;
struct Node *next;
};

void insert(int x, struct Node **pL){
printf("insert\n");
if(*pL == NULL){
    printf("inside if\n");
    struct Node *pN;
    pN = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    (*pN).value = x;
    (*pN).next = NULL;
    return;
}
if (*pL != NULL){
    printf("inside else\n");
    insert(x, &(((*pL)->next)));
}
printf("end insert\n");
};

void printList(struct Node *L){
while (L != NULL){
printf("%d", (*L).value);
printList((*L).next);
}
return;
};

main(){
printf("main\n");
struct Node* L;
//L).next = NULL;
int i;
printf("for loop\n");
for (i = 3; i < 20; i+=2){
    printf("%d\n", i);
    insert(i, &L);
}
printList(L);
};
```

Comment: `struct Node* L = NULL;` might fix some of it

Comment: I tried that already, it just delays the inevtiable issue.  Since it recalls it recurvisely, eventually it hits the point where it needs to check for NULL and all goes to hell.

Comment: (to save us time reading it all) where exactly is the problem? which function?

Comment: the insert function, the first if statement

Comment: oh i see - you create pn but don't put it in the list

Comment: when I run this I never even get inside the first if statement.

But please elaborate on what you're talking about.  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I suggest your to make `*(L).value` and `*(L).next` as `L->value` and `L->next`. Helps to make the code readable.

Comment: @ChristianBaker use the code in my first comment, and it will go always in the fitrst if

Comment: Sweeeeeet, the insert is working.  Now it just won't print :(

Comment: There's a printList function if anyone wants to check that out

Comment: @ChristianBaker i'm typing up an ideone version now, just a minute..

Comment: Add `*PL = Pn;` before the first `return` inside the `insert` function. Of course your must initialize `L` as `NULL` inside main.

Comment: @Sundar that's not all of it, but i'll post an answer shortly

Comment: I just made the node *pL instead of *pN.  So every instance where you see a "*pN" has been replaced by "*pL"

Comment: inside your `printList` function make the `while` as `if`.

Comment: is [this](http://ideone.com/hmRx8t) ok? the changes are: use of typedef struct, replace while with if, and if's to check that a non-null pL has also a non-null next, etc

Comment: yo this stuff is totally working, thanks a bunch guys.  If there's more stuff that I get stuck on is it cool if I just comment here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in `main` you need to initialise `L`:

```
struct Node* L = NULL;
```

Second, in `insert` when you allocate the new node `pN`, you are not assigning it to the `pL`, i.e., it doesn't get inserted. Put this right before the `return;` in `insert`:

```
*pL = pN;
```

(Also you could remove the `return` and change `if (*pL != NULL)` into `else`.)

Then, in `printList` you are both iterating with a `while` loop, and with recursion. Choose one, not both, e.g.,:

```
while (L) {
    printf("%d\n", L->value);
    L = L->next;
}
```

Also, throughout your code you can replace `(*pointer_to_struct).field` with `pointer_to_struct->field` for better style.